# Mongodb sharding on the same machine with different disks

Tags: mongodb, server

I am developing a project with a mongodb database and now I am researching to put it into production.

I am going to deploy the database on my own server, that is why I am looking at the best way to do it.

I had initially thought of creating a raid 5 system on my server and hosting the mongodb storage on it, however after some reading I discovered that this doesn't make much sense since mongodb has its own replication system through sharding.

But my question is if I can implement sharding on a single machine and that each of these replicas run on a different hard drive to avoid losing data if one crashes or if I need to have different machines to create on each of these replicas.

I hope someone can help me with this, I'm actually pretty new to mongodb.
thanks

Comment: Don't mistake [sharding](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/sharding/) with  [replication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/replication/). Replication on a single machine does not make much sense, because if this machine goes offline then your MongoDB is gone - as simple it is. RAID provides high availability on physical storage which is a different thing.

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit Ok I understand... My confusion is because some time ago I read that it didn't make sense to use raid for mongodb since mongo's own replication existed. But I understand that for an environment where there is only one physical server, it would be interesting to use a raid system since, as mongo replication tells me, not to use anything. It is not like this?

Comment: From which fault do you like to protect your system? A broken hard-disk? Then go for RAID. A server outage (incl. loss of connectivity - which is quite a common fault)? Then use multiple hosts with MongoDB replication. In an enterprise environment you will use most probably both of them.

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit But if I have an environment with multiple servers configured with mongodb replication. What is the point of using RAID in each of them? If the hard disk of a server crashes, I can recover the information from another host... wouldn't a RAID system be unnecessary?

Comment: When a disk in RAID fails then you simply replace it, that's it. Restoring a crashed MongoDB replica set member takes more effort. Apart from that, RAID may improve the performance. Have also a look at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/#raid

Comment: Ohh thank you very much for your help now I understand everything better and why it is useful to use RAID